# Flash: Memory usage is low but framerate keeps dropping

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

So I'm working on a puzzle game in flash. For all intents and purposes it's like Tetris. I spawn blocks, they move around the screen, then they get destroyed and disappear. I was having some trouble with the memory usage being too high over time so I read up on memory management and I think I have that figured out now. It's definitely climbing slower than it was before, but the framerate is still taking a huge dive after playing for a while. If it's not a memory leak what else could be causing this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either 2 of these it think:
  - It would very well be that you are deleting stuff from the display-list but still have references in other places( like arrays ) that are still being processed. This keeps building up and completely hogs your game. ( but Flash can easily handle tons of objects )

or

-Your algorithm, even though simplistic, is flawed and is doing more work than necessary. Memory leaks are nearly impossible in AS3 unless you loose an object that holds a reference to an object you can't reach anymore ( like Events that aren't destroyed and never have their weak flag set to true).

This combined with the above one can really tear down the performance.

Comment: Hmm, at what amount of memory do you think the game could no longer handle 30 FPS? Because the game stays around 30 and no higher than 40.

Comment: It's not the amount of memory, rather the object your game needs to process. Keeping stuff in memory but not doing anything with them shouldn't directly affect the performance unless you do something with it. If your objects aren't rendering after removal, then you took them out of your display list. But you should also check if they are removed from arrays etc. The Garbage collector will only destroy the data if exactly 0 pointers are pointing to the data.

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've taken care of this. Every time I destroy a block it looks like this:

blockHolder.removeChild(block);

delete(block);

blocks.splice(blockIndex, 1);

Comment: Seems to be clean. What software are you using? Flashdevelop for example has a profiler which allows you to see various stats on object types, like the amount that are in memory.

Comment: I'm just using Flash CS5 but I am currently using thMiner profiler but I don't really know what I'm doing with it or what I should be looking for.

Comment: I just looked at their website, you might want to look at the function profiler to see which function takes the longest. You also want to look at what type is occupying the most memory with the Instantiation Profiler. This should give you a big indication where in your code it goes bad.

Comment: Darn it, well I thought I'd found the problem but it just lead me to another problem. I have a few looping animations (movieclips) in my game and when they appear on screen the Memory Profiler shows a steady increase in Shape objects, it's like Flash is recreating the shapes every iteration through the loop but never deleting them. Any idea what might be causing this?

Comment: At what column are you looking? Add/Del/Current/Cumul ?

Comment: @Cyborg771 *Hmm, at what amount of memory do you think the game could no longer handle 30 FPS?* - it depends on your RAM. When you have no more RAM left, your OS will use disk space instead, and it's 1000 times slower to access it. Also, if you're in a debugging mode, debugger will have to maintain more data making it affect your performance directly.

Answer (score 2):

http://gamedev.michaeljameswilliams.com/2009/03/25/avoider-game-tutorial-12/ you should visit this part of that tutorial, it will probably contain your problem, which is for example, not unloading  the childs you create and instead just freeze them out of view. I could try to tell you details but check that out, at least you should get a lot of really useful tips.